# Ошибка выполнения (Java), задача на дерево отрезков

Tags: java, дерево

Видимо напортачил с классами. Помогите разобраться.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class node
{
    int ones, twos, add;
}


class tree
{
    //int[] st = new int[1 << 18];
    node[] st = new node[1<<18];
    //В вершину VSun сверху производится проталкивание значения add (0 ≤ add ≤ 2). Вершина VSun
    //является левым сыном, если SunType = 'L' и правым если SunType = 'R'. Отцу вершины VSun
    //соответствует отрезок [LeftPos, RightPos], Middle = (LeftPos + RightPos) / 2. Будем add
    //раз производить в вершине VSun циклический сдвиг количества нулей, единиц и двоек. Каждый
    //циклический сдвиг соответствует проталкиванию единицы из отца в VSun.
    public void MakeShift(int VSun, int add, char SunType, int LeftPos, int Middle, int RightPos)
    {
        st[VSun].add = (st[VSun].add + add) % 3;
        while (add>0)
        {
            //Количество двоек становится равным числу единиц. Количество единиц становится равным числу нулей.
            int _Ones = st[VSun].ones;

            //Количество единиц становится равным числу нулей. Проталкивание происходит в левом сыне, если
            //SunType = 'L'. Если VSun является левым сыном, то длина соответствующего ему отрезка равна
            //Middle – LeftPos + 1. Если правым сыном, то RightPos – Middle.
            if (SunType=='L') st[VSun].ones = Middle - LeftPos + 1 - st[VSun].ones - st[VSun].twos;
            else st[VSun].ones = RightPos - Middle - st[VSun].ones - st[VSun].twos;

            //Количество двоек становится равным числу единиц.
            st[VSun].twos = _Ones;
        }
    }

    //Если значение add в вершине v отлично от нуля, то следует его протолкнуть на один уровень
    //вниз. После проталкивания add в вершине v ставим равным нулю. Значение add в сыновьях v
    //увеличиваем на протолкнутое значение. Пересчитываем значения ones и twos в сыновьях.
    void Push(int v, int LeftPos, int Middle, int RightPos)
    {
        MakeShift(2 * v, st[v].add, 'L', LeftPos, Middle, RightPos);
        MakeShift(2 * v + 1, st[v].add, 'R', LeftPos, Middle, RightPos);
        st[v].add = 0;
    }

    //Вершине v соответствует отрезок [LeftPos; RightPos ]. Функция IncValue
    //прибавляет ко всем элементам отрезка[Left; Right] значение 1.
    public void IncValue(int v, int LeftPos, int RightPos, int Left, int Right)
    {
        if (Left > Right) return;
        if (LeftPos == Left && RightPos == Right)
        {
            st[v].add = (st[v].add + 1) % 3;
            int _Ones = st[v].ones;
            st[v].ones = Right - Left + 1 - st[v].ones - st[v].twos;
            st[v].twos = _Ones;
            return;
        }
        int Middle = (LeftPos + RightPos) / 2;

        //Проведем проталкивание, если add не равно нулю.
        Push(v, LeftPos, Middle, RightPos);

        //Рекурсивно обрабатываем левого и правого сына текущей вершины дерева отрезков.
        IncValue(2 * v, LeftPos, Middle, Left, Math.min(Middle, Right));
        IncValue(2 * v + 1, Middle + 1, RightPos, Math.max(Left, Middle + 1), Right);

        //Пересчитываем количество единиц и двоек на отрезке, соответствующему вершине v, через соответствующие значения детей.
        st[v].ones = st[2 * v].ones + st[2 * v + 1].ones;
        st[v].twos = st[2 * v].twos + st[2 * v + 1].twos;
    }

    //Вершине v соответствует отрезок [LeftPos; RightPos]. Функция Query возвращает количество нулей на отрезке [Left; Right].
    int Query(int v, int LeftPos, int RightPos, int Left, int Right)
    {
        if (Left > Right) return 0;

        //Количество нулей на отрезке равно длине отрезка минус количество единиц и двоек на нем.
        if (LeftPos == Left && RightPos == Right) return (RightPos - LeftPos + 1) - st[v].ones - st[v].twos;
        int Middle = (LeftPos + RightPos) / 2;
        Push(v, LeftPos, Middle, RightPos);
        return Query(2 * v, LeftPos, Middle, Left, Math.min(Middle, Right)) +
            Query(2 * v + 1, Middle + 1, RightPos, Math.max(Left, Middle + 1), Right);
    }
}


public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        tree x = new tree();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i < m; i++)
        {
            int type = in.nextInt();
            int L = in.nextInt();
            int R = in.nextInt();
            if(type==1)
            {
                System.out.println(x.Query(1, 0, n - 1, L, R));
            } else {
                x.IncValue(1, 0, n - 1, L, R);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как-то не похоже на дерево отрезков. По карйней мере, я пишу его совершенно не так.

Comment: Согласен, скорее имитация дерева, но суть не в этом. Я ищу не ошибку в вычислениях, а ошибку в применении языка.

Comment: @AntonKuperman так если ищешь ошибку в применении языка, какая именно ошибка на выходе?